# Wikipedia Lucene search possible with REST-API?

Tags: solr, lucene, wikipedia-api

I get about 1-25 search words and would like to search in a private wiki if a article exists (in article text search) where all the words or at least many words are occuring. (or instead of and Operator).

Right now i'm using:
http://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=nutch&format=xml
and
http://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=nutch&format=xml

the first doesn't include a score or has an relevance order, that's why i'm prefer the later one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Extension available for MediaWiki called Lucene-Search:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Lucene-search